# Looking for a proof that the number of non-zero derivatives of a polynomial $f(x)$ is equal to the number of its roots

Tags: calculus, analysis

I can see why this works for a root $p$ with multiplicity $k\geq 1$, when $f(x)=(x-p)^k$.

But, why is that true if $f(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)$ has distinct roots $x_1\neq x_2\neq \cdots \neq x_n$?

Is it something to do with Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem?

Comment: I guess that instead of "continuous functions" you mean "polynomials"? And by "non-zero derivations" you mean non-identically-null derivatives. If so, and if already know the factorization theorem, then it's almost trivial: just expand the product.

Comment: this question derives from analysis,i am not asking why the polynom of order n has n roots,it is clear as explained below,i am asking for a proof  $f^(k^)(x)\neq0$ for every $1<=k<=n$

Comment: i know that the the n+1 derivation of $f(x)=a0+a1x+a2x^2+..+anx^n$  & $an\neq0$ will result in zero value,i am looking for a proof based on lagrange mid-value theorem,is there one?

Answer (score 1):

Throughout, suppose we're working over a field of characteristic $0$.

Let
$$f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$$
be a polynomial of degree $n$, so that $a_n \ne 0$. Then its derivative
$$f'(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+1)a_{k+1}x^{k}$$
has leading coefficient $na_n$, which is nonzero if $n>0$. So if $n>0$ then this has degree $n-1$. Apply some sort of induction argument and you'll see that this implies that a polynomial of degree $n$ (over a field of characteristic $0$) has exactly $n$ nonzero derivatives, and that its $(n+1)^{\text{th}}$ derivative is $0$.

So if you're working over $\mathbb{C}$ then a consequence of the fundamental theorem of algebra is that
$$\#\text{nonzero derivatives} = \deg f = \#\text{roots}$$

This is true over any algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. In fact, it's true for a polynomial of degree $n$ over any algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ or $p>n$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not true over all functions and fields, but is certainly true of polynomials over the complex numbers.  This is known as the [fundamental theorem of algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

Comment: yes,i know it is true,i am looking for proof,the fundamental theorem of algebra is irrelevant for the proof as i already given the form $f(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)..(x-x_n)$